# Equivalent of HttpRuntime.BinDirectory Asp.Net 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

```
    public virtual string GetBinDirectory()
{
    if (HostingEnvironment.IsHosted)
    {
        //hosted
        return HttpRuntime.BinDirectory;
    }

    return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
}
```

I have changed my code, below, after inheriting Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting, to what I believe is correct but am stumped on the HttpRuntime.

```
    public virtual string GetBinDirectory()
    {
        if (_hosting.IsProduction())
        {
            //hosted
            return HttpRuntime.BinDirectory; (Stumped)
        }

        return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions.PlatformServices.Default.Application

In the Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions nuget package.

Note that Asp.Net 5 is highly unstable and the team has changed the package, namespace, accessibility, class name and means of accessing this functionality with almost every release in the past 6 months.